# How can I use std::binary_search using just a key?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I have some data that is stored in a sorted vector. This vector is sorted by some key. I know the STL has an algorithm for checking if an element is in this sorted list. This means I can write something like this:

```
struct MyData { int key; OtherData data; };
struct MyComparator
{
  bool operator()( const MyData & d1, const MyData & d2 ) const
  {
    return d1.key < d2.key;
  }
};

bool isKeyInVector( int key, const std::vector<MyData> &v )
{
   MyData thingToSearchFor;
   thingToSearchFor.key = key;
   return std::binary_search( v.begin(), v.end(), thingToSearchFor, MyComparator() );
}
```

However I find the construction of the "thingToSearchFor" object inelegant. Is there a better way? Something similar to this?

```
struct MyComparator2
{
  bool operator()( const MyData & d1, const MyData & d2 ) const
  {
    return d1.key < d2.key;
  }
};

bool isKeyInVector2( int key, const std::vector<MyData> &v )
{
   return std::binary_search( v.begin(), v.end(), key, MyComparator2() );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do:

```
struct MyComparator
{
    bool operator()(int d1, const MyData & d2) const
    {
        return d1 < d2.key;
    }

    bool operator()(const MyData & d1, int d2) const
    {
        return d1.key < d2;
    }
};
```

The predicate is called like `pred(value, ...)` or `pred(..., value)`, so just take in the value directly.

Comment: This seems to work, but seems to violate the requirement that the predicate be a Strict Weak Ordering. In particular from the SGI STL site "Second argument type: The type of the Strict Weak Ordering's second argument. The first argument type and second argument type must be the same."

Comment: @Michael: I don't see any such requirements in the C++ standard, looking at §25.3. SGI != Standard Library.

Comment: I also can find no mention of this in the standard. Looks like this is the way to do it.